# Array is null @ $DynamicGroupSet

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

```
Import-Module AzureADPreview

$keyCarrierGroups = @()
$DynamicGroupSet = @()
$storeInfo = @{}

$keyCarrierGroups = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {DisplayName -like "*_Key_Carriers"})
foreach ($group in $keyCarrierGroups){
$DynamicGroupSet.Add((Get-AzureADMSGroup -Id $group.Name.Split("_")[1]))
}
foreach($group in $DynamicGroupSet){$storeInfo.add($group.DisplayName.Split("_")[0],$group.Id)}
foreach($store in $storeinfo.Keys){Set-AzureADMSGroup -Id $storeinfo.Item($store) -MembershipRule {(user.Department -contains $store) -and (user.extensionAttribute3 -eq "A") -and (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10005") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10006") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10013") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10064") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10070") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10078") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10146") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "205") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10158") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10173") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "40057") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10012") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10022") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10023") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10104") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10123") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "70017") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "70029") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "70056") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "70099") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80004") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80016") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80076") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80143") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80156") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10166") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10179") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80178") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80217") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80224") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10010") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80003") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80011") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80014") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80066") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80090") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10136") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10159") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10181") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10183") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "10185") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "70128") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80177") -or (user.extensionAttribute6 -contains "80191")}}
```

So far I have tried a $DynamicGroupSet += and .add. When Debugging the array is null. I have confirmed (Get-AzureADMSGroup -Id $group.Name.Split("_")[1]) returns what I am looking for. Cannot figure out why its not populating in the array.

Comment: the `.Add()` method for arrays is ... non-functional. they are fixed size and cannot be added to. instead, they copy to a new, one-item-larger array when you use `+=`.  ///// your store info collection is a hashtable and DOES have a working `.Add()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenter [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) correcty stated, the `.Add()` method doesn't work for arrays. When I call `.Add()` on an array I get the following error message which explains it pretty much:

> Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a
> fixed size."

PowerShell's `+=` operator works around this by recreating the array with the new size everytime you call the operator. Of course this is not very efficient, so `+=` should be avoided unless the array will be very small.

In most cases `+=` isn't even necessary, because PowerShell automatically (and more efficiently) creates an array when you assign the output of a cmdlet or a script block to a variable. You can even assign the output of control statements such as `foreach`, `if` and `switch` to a variable.

So, remove this line...

```
$DynamicGroupSet = @()
```

...and do this instead:

```
$DynamicGroupSet = foreach ($group in $keyCarrierGroups){
    Get-AzureADMSGroup -Id $group.Name.Split("_")[1]
}
```

You see that the code even becomes much cleaner.

PowerShell automatically captures the output of everything that runs in the `foreach` body and adds it to `$DynamicGroupSet`, which will be an array if there are more than one elements.